# Electric Light Switch Box Screw Hole Cracked

Tags: wiring, light

I was installing a new light switch and then noticed the hole for the electric box screw was cracked as seen in photo, the top left screw hole is cracked.

[image: wall box with damaged screw hole]

Is there anything I can do to fix/repair this without replacing the wall box unit?

I found this thing online called a [G Clip](http://www.g-clip.us/) anyone used this before? Or know if it will work/ is safe?

[image: G-clip image from their site]
<sup>Image of G Clip from g-clip.us.</sup>

Comment: That G-Clip looks like a great solution. The only problem is that it doesn't say anything about UL listing. While I can't imagine it would be an *actual* safety hazard (it is a simple piece of metal and installed in a way that it can't fall on any wires), technically an inspector could reject it based on having something inside the box that isn't a UL listed device.

Comment: the G clip fits above the box ... it is unclear if there is space for it

Comment: Good point, @jsotola. However, that does look like it's just drywall, space could be made. The key point seems to be the lack of UL listing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use my go-to subfloor adhesive made with polyurethane paste that is as strong as any plastic or sheet metal smeared into the cracks , surface wall and the holes at least 1mm thick for this job and then next day when cured , drill an undersized hole for a suitable sized metal screw or self tapping screw.

Very strong. I use it to fix everything from furniture frames, cracked plastic, metal structures, drawer slides. It's Polyurethane with fibre particles. The more expensive tubes are stronger but not necessary here. Apply with any disposable flat tool.

They also get rid of hardwood floor squeeks if you can access it. I  apply a thin bead along the subfloor plywood interface joint to cross-struts in an open ceiling basement. Applied like silicon caulk.  No more squeeks.

All [hardware stores carry this or similar.](https://www.amazon.ca/LePage-1654126-Subfloor-Adhesive-295ml/dp/B019GIT2GO/ref=asc_df_B019GIT2GO/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=335370215957&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17068380319656665530&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9000793&hvtargid=pla-757791161971&psc=1)

The low VOC types take a day to get hard and a few to fully cure.  The older high VOC types cured in 15 minutes to an hour.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent idea. Is it UL listed for installation into a junction box? This is the type of thing that _could_ get flagged during an inspection (either for this project or a pre-sale inspection).

Comment: A pre-sale inspection will not catch such things (adhesive or G-clip or whatever) - nobody is going to open up receptacles and switches as part of a pre-sale inspection unless they find a loose cover plate/receptacle/switch. The only inspection that will catch it is as part of a permitting process.

Comment: @TonyStewart thanks for the recommendation my only worry with that is, is it flammable? Or what temperature is it rated to?

Comment: It's not inflammable but considering it is sealed from air and it's the MARR CONNECTOR Polyurethane I would be concerned about 1st.